# Why the Regex take minimum 2 character to validate a string?

Tags: regex

Why the Regex take minimum 2 character to validate a string ?

/^[^\s]\w*[^\s]$/g

Exm- ab , bc will be validated true
     but a , b , c will not be validated true

Comment: `[^\s]` matches 1 char other than whitespace and you have 2 such patterns. See https://regex101.com/r/6qOLAR/1

Comment: /^[^\s]\w*$/g   this also take 2 character to validate. Could you please explain the reason ? @Wiktor

Comment: [No, it matches 1-char strings.](https://regex101.com/r/6qOLAR/2)